# JaxRS: HttpServletRequest is null into ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I've created this filter:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class BearerFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Context private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
    {
        this.request.getHeaders();
    }
}
```

When `filter` method is reached, `this.request` property is `null`.

I'm using jaxrs and I'm using this [oltu library](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/Index). It needs [an `HttpServletRequest` object](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/OAuth+2.0+Resource+Server).

This is my rest application:

```
@ApplicationPath(value = "cmng")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        resources.add(AccountEndpoint.class);

        return resources;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

        singletons.add(new CORSFilter());
        singletons.add(new BearerFilter());

        return singletons;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems your container is not injecting the dependency. I am not sure if it can be done in filters . You can also retrieve headers using `requestContext.getHeaders()`

Comment: I'm using this [oltu library](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/Index). It needs [an `HttpServletRequest` object](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/OAuth+2.0+Resource+Server).

Comment: Try to add `@Provider` to your class

Comment: It's already annotated (a miswritting)...

Comment: Have you setup the application with a class that extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`?

Comment: Yes. You can watch it on post (I've just edited it).